# Kafka topic data is not getting deleted in windows

Tags: apache-kafka

Kafka topic data is not getting deleted in windows after proper configuration of the log retention period.

Following errors are getting recorded in the Kafka server logs.

> Caused by: java.nio.file.FileSystemException:
>   \tmp\kafka-logs\TopicName-2\00000000000000007262.log ->
>   \tmp\kafka-logs\TopicName -2\00000000000000007262.log.deleted: The
>   process cannot access the file because it is being used by another
>   process.
>
> Uncaught exception in scheduled task 'kafka-log-retention'
>   (kafka.utils.KafkaScheduler) kafka.common.KafkaStorageException:
>   Failed to change the log file suffix from  to .deleted for log segment
>   7262

Comment: You can try to use a fix in [this pull request](https://github.com/apache/kafka/pull/12331).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is related to this bug on Windows:

[KAFKA-1194 Kafka issue on MS Windows](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-1194)